# how to call different sonar dashboard from sonar runner using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have created a separate Sonar dashboard (customize dashboard) and I have different types of projects.So I want to analyse code using SonarQube and want different dashboard for different types.
I see default Sonar dashboard, all projects come but how can I separate when I call from sonar runner using Jenkins?Is there any sonar properties for this?
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question... You don't "call a dashboard", this doesn't mean anything. Please edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are believing that it is possible to define during the analysis the dashboard to be used. If so, this is not how it works.

I use different dashboards showing different widgets and measures in different order, specialized on a technology: I don't look at the same metrics for Java or Cobol. Now, these dashboard are available for all your analysis. Although, you could have a specific user (or different groups of users) for each technology, so when they log, they can see only dashboards specific to this group.

Hope it helps, but it's true that you question is not clear.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for replying both.Yes, you got me right.Let me explain the context -From Jenkins using sonar runner, I am invoking sonar analysis.Once analysis is successfull, I can see the results in sonar dashboard for all the different types of projects.I see one option to create dashboard in Sonar.What I am looking is -as all projects analysis are coming in the same sonar dashboard (home).Is there any way while invoking from Sonar Runner to display the analysis result in new sonar dashboard which I have created (not in the default dashboard)?My current dashboard is mix of all diff. types of projs.

Comment: You have mentione dits not possible..but was just checking this as I have two types of Projects and wanted to have seperate sonar dashboard for each type.Now my home dashboard is mixuture of both types and have many projects and hence itsn't much user friendly

Comment: Again, all your analysis will be available in the default dashboard or any dashboard that you create. You cannot 'invoke Sonar Runner' or Jenkins to display the results in a specific dashboard. They do the analysis, and SonarQube display the data.

Comment: A possible answer would be to specialize your dashboard with a different user/login. I have a specialized dashboard I have customized with different widgets to display specific data for my Cobol analysis. I created it while logged as admin. Now, when I launch SonarQube, I can see the results of this Cobol analysis with the default dashboard, but the specialized dashboard I created is not available until I log as admin.

Comment: So, to be clear: 1.Sonar Runner/Jenkins do the analysis 2.You define dashboards to display differently the results of the analysis. 3.Playing with different users/logins might be your solution.